# Run Selenium EdgeDriver(Chromium) in private mode using Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

I am usign Selenium with Version 81.0.416.72 (Official build) (64-bit) of Edge web driver.

I would like to start the browser in private mode. here is the code i am using

```
    EdgeOptions eOptions = new EdgeOptions();
    eOptions.setCapability("InPrivate", true);
    driver = new EdgeDriver(eOptions);
```

However the browser still opens in regular mode. I believe the problem is with the "InPrivate" being the wrong capability name.

Please advise,

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add argument `inprivate` to make Edge Chromium open in Private mode using Selenium WebDriver. This needs to use with [selenium-webdriver alpha version](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/)(selenium-server-4.0.0-alpha-5).

Then, use the following code to Open Edge InPrivate mode (change the webdriver path to yours).

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeOptions;

public class Edgeauto {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "D:\\webdriver\\msedgedriver.exe"); 
        EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions();
        edgeOptions.addArguments("-inprivate");
        WebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver(edgeOptions); 
        driver.get("https://bing.com");
    }
}
```

[Note] please download the matching version of Microsoft Edge Driver from [this page](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).